# Efficient way to handle translations with Multisite Wordpress installation

Tags: multisite, multi-language

We inherited from a Wordpress multisite install to achieve localisation with more than five different languages.

Thanks to the [Multilingual Press](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press/), we have a reasonable setup where `href lang` are well setup and translations for a given page are all visible in one place because they are stacked in Wordpress editor (see picture below).

We use mainly Wordpress for pages (not for posts). Our pages have different html layouts so our Wordpress pages contain a substantial amount of html elements (`<div>` `<img>` etc.)

Therefore the translation process is very tedious. We have access to the translated content as [YAML files](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html). We need to replace in DOM elements the translated strings for each language. I have used Jekyll in the past and [interpolation for localisation](https://github.com/Anthony-Gaudino/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin#5-usage) was a good way to handle this problem.

My question is then, how would you tackle the problem? I see several options but others are also welcomed:

- integrate a "Jekyll like generator" to create all translations from a reference page containing only the interpolated html content. How could we do that in practice?
- move every html content to .php theme files and use php functions for translations (but keep in mind we have many pages with various layouts, no blog posts).
- ...

[image: Multilanguage site]